# Does Blood Run have different Rewards?

Tags: the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine

Are additional things rewarded to the player if he defeats the beast of beauclaire on their first encounter?

Answer (score 1):

If you [defeat the beast](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Run) instead of dying to it you will be rewarded with an additional 1000xp.

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know, you could die here and not get a game over.